# Execute a function from other view controller

Tags: swift

I have the following interfaces:

[image]

In the table view I set the new values for the user and I would like to call the function to update the data from the server when the button "Done" from the main view is pressed.

How I can do it?

I have tried:

```
@IBAction func doneTapped(_ sender: Any){
    ProfileEditingTableViewController().updateData()
}
```

But all the text fields from the other view are null because it seems to be a new instance of ProfileEditingTableViewController.
updateData() can't be static.

```
class ProfileEditingViewController: UIViewController {


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }

    @IBAction func cancelButton(_ sender: Any) {
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    @IBAction func doneTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        // Here I have to save the data from the other View
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

}

class ProfileEditingTableViewController: UITableViewController {

 func updateData() {
 ... 
 }
}
```

Comment: You probably need to handle this in the `prepareForSegue` method

Comment: You can either pass the reference of the other viewController to this viewController or use notifications.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calling method in another view controller from modal view controller using a delegate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51809686/calling-method-in-another-view-controller-from-modal-view-controller-using-a-del)

Answer (score 0):

This line

```
ProfileEditingTableViewController().updateData()
```

is incorrect as it creates a new instance, you need to use delegate to access the presented `ProfileEditingTableViewController`

```
class ProfileEditingTableViewController: UITableViewController  {

  var profileInstance: ProfileEditingViewController!

}
```

When you present information from profile:

```
let info = //

info.delegate = self // here self is the profile instance
```

Then use:

```
profileInstance.updateData()
```

//

**Edit:** connect the segue source to the vc itself ( yellow circular icon ) , this inside ( `ProfileEditingViewController`)

```
self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToNext", sender: nil)
```

//

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    super.prepare(for: segue, sender: sender)
    if segue.identifier == "goToNext" {
      let des = segue.destination as! ProfileEditingTableViewController
      des.profileInstance = self
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you explain me the reason to use `let info = ... info.delegate = self` I don't understand it.

Comment: Here you link the presented object of profile , so you can access it inside informationVC

Comment: Do you segue ??

Comment: Yes, is a embed segue.

Comment: `Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value` in `profileInstance.updateData()`

Comment: I have update the post withe the two view controllers, maybe it helps to explain me.

Comment: Value of type 'ProfileEditingViewController' has no member 'delegate' in `des.delegate = self`